# list sqlite tables with dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

I can use `dplyr` to connect to a `sqlite` database:

```
library(dplyr)
mydb<- src_sqlite("DATA/mydb.db")
```

How can I list the tables in `mydb`? I couldn't find anything about that in [the help file](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/databases.html)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
# get sample databases from: http://chinookdatabase.codeplex.com/

library(dplyr)
mydb <- src_sqlite("Chinook_Sqlite.sqlite")
src_tbls(mydb)

##  [1] "Album"         "Artist"        "Customer"      "Employee"    
##  [5] "Genre"         "Invoice"       "InvoiceLine"   "MediaType"    
##  [9] "Playlist"      "PlaylistTrack" "Track"
```